# .NET Open Source CMS to use as framework with Jquery and MVP

Tags: .net, content-management-system, mvp, umbraco, n2

I've been reading some articles about Open Source CMS.

I am looking for something like a .NET CMS framework that implements MVP (no MVC) structural pattern, jQuery so i can add my own classes, UserControls, Pages and whatever i want.

I've heard about Umbraco and N2. Not sure if those are the best or simply what i am looking for.

Does anybody know about these frameworks? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Umbraco with the MVP pattern (version 4.7). It is quite good, though it does force you to use User Controls and Master Pages. It does do a lot in XSLT, but it is easy to bypass this so you are using pure C#.

It's very easy to pick up as well. Worth a try, this is the only open source CMS I have worked with so far though.

Also have a look at Orchard.

Comment: i've been looking at DNN and Umbraco... and my question is more like... Does it really worth it to create our website on top of this "frameworks"? I mean, other than the "layout" already done and a couple of more features... you have to write all the code (which i ma happy with). So i guess if you take one week and create a very solid "layout" using Masterpages, CSS and divs... you got pretty much what you need to start coding. The rest is just create usercontrols and that's it. 
that's my personal opinion after playing around with DNN live demo. Unless you wanna use all those predefined mods

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. It is worth using a pattern like MVP which is more a code structure than a framework, but it makes it a lot easier to unit test, and the structure makes for a cleaner, more abstracted way of coding within webforms.

But it is personal preference and also depends on how complex your site will be, if it is just a small site, just continue as best practices state, if it is likely to grow, it is worth getting your architecture right, then you'll be ok when it starts growing changing. :)